# I can't find any difference between Negative and positive numbers.

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose there are two adjacent numbers side by side x and y, ie y is 1 unit bigger than x.
So is -x and -y.
I have tried many calculations such as changing the polarity of one of them the subtracting or adding to try and see if i can reduce negative numbers to -1 and positive numbers to 1 using same operations on x, -x and y, -y and reached the conclusion that it's impossible to differentiate between positive and negative numbers if there was no sign.
all this assuming we can differentiate 1 and -1.
Is there something I am missing?
sorry if I come out as really dumb or incomprehensible I wasn't good at English or Maths.
Edit: we can add subtract the numbers, but we cannot multiply them into each other or itself but we can multiply them to other numbers, and we cannot divide.

Comment: " So is $-x$ and $-y$."  No: $-x$ is one unit bigger the $-y$.

Comment: Not following.  What would it mean to "differentiate" between two numbers?  If, say $1$ represented the money in your pocket, and $-1$ represented the money you owed someone, you could differentiate between them then, yes?

Comment: $1^2=1$ but $(-1)^2\ne -1$.

Comment: So you're trying to somehow "test" whether a number is positive or negative. What operations are you allowed to use? Are you allowed to use the absolute value? You could try to add a number to its absolute value, divide the result by two ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe In the Number Line -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 x or -x is always in the left and -2<-1.

Comment: @MattiP. we can add subtract the numbers, but we cannot multiply them into each other or itself but we can multiply them to other numbers, and we cannot divide.

Comment: I think this question can be boiled down to observing a reflection in the vertical mirror line at $x=0$ on a number line. Yes: the negative part of a number line is a reflection of the positive part of the number line (but with/without the minus symbol)... This can be summarised by the statement: $-(-x) = x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely right, there is no way to distinguish positive from negative numbers with only addition and subtraction!

To distinguish positive from negative, you need something else: **multiplication**.  Suppose you have some number $n$ and you don't know if it is $+1$ or $-1$.  No problem, you can easily find out. Just multiply $n\cdot n$ and see what you get.  If you get $n$ back again, then $n$ was $1$.  If $n\cdot n = -n$, then $n$ was $-1$.

Here's  a more general way to put it.  We can divide numbers into positive and negative with the properties that:

- When we multiply a positive number and a negative number, we always get a **negative** number
- When we multiply positive by positive, or negative by negative, we always get a **positive** number

If you exchange "positive" and "negative" here you get something very different that is not like the way numbers really behave.

But to find a property like this, that distinguishes positive from negative, addition and subtraction won't do; you need multiplication.

---

(There's even a fancy mathematician way to express your discovery:

> The map $$f:n\mapsto -n$$ is an automorphism of $\langle\Bbb Z, +\rangle$.

The $\Bbb Z$ means the integers.  “$\langle\Bbb Z, +\rangle$” means the integers, with the extra structure that comes from the addition operation.  (And also subtraction, which to a mathematician is a kind of addition because $a-b$ is just $a + (-b)$.)

“$f$ is an automorphism” means that when you do the operation $f$ of exchanging $n$ for $-n$, all the structure of the $\langle\Bbb Z, +\rangle$ system is retained, with no changes at all.

When you include multiplication, you get a a more complicated structure called $\langle\Bbb Z, +, \cdot\rangle$, and $f$ is *not* an automorphism of this structure.)

Comment: Is it too late to mention we cannot multiply the numbers to itself or into each other. but we can multiply them to other numbers. I am going to edit it in the Question, if its still not possible that way, I will accept this answer.

Comment: Even a little bit of multiplication lets me distinguish positive from negative. You say I can't multiply $n\cdot n$? No problem, I can still distinguish $+1$ from $-1$. I compute $n\cdot (n+1)$. If what I get is equal to  $n+n$, then what I started with  was $+1$. If it isn't, what I started with was $-1$.

Comment: so if n was positive? I will get 1 and if negative I will get -1?
-5.(-5+1) = -5.(-4) I get 20 and if it was positive 5.(5+1) = 5.(6) I get 30, am I missing something? but I do see we can differentiate them but I was looking for some small value as in the results like -1 or 1, is that possible?

Comment: If you want a single operation that turns all positive numbers into $+1$ and all negative numbers into $-1$, and that only involves addition, subtraction, and multiplication, that's not going to be possible, because we can prove that any such operation must turn very large numbers into other very large numbers.

Comment: On the other hand if you want some operation that turns every number into $+1$, you can use $n·n - (n-1)·(n-1)$. No matter what $n$ is,  you can be 100% certain that you have computed $+1$ and not anything else.  Now you can add multiples of $+1$'s to $n$ and see if the result is closer to $0$ or farther away.

Comment: I tested it then remembered I'm not allowed to multiply n by itself, because I don't know what n is in the first place, will it still be possible to produce two distinct absolute values no matter if they are big or small, but we are not allowed to multiply n to itself or n+-1 to n.

Comment: I don't understand why you would be allowed to multiply $n\cdot (n+1)$ but not $n\cdot n$.  But if you are allowed to compute $(n+1)\cdot(n-1) - (n+2)\cdot(n-2) - 2$ you will always get exactly $1$.

Comment: no we cannot multiply n.n or n.(n-1 or n+1) we can (n+1)*z

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149979/discussion-between-zetock-and-mjd).

Comment: Thank you for the invitation, but I avoid chat on SE.  Let's take the suggestion to move to chat as an indication that we're not reaching a conclusion in a satisfactory time and just both move on.