# Is it possible to differentiate between Negative and Positive Numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We have an unknown number x.

we can subtract, add and multiply, but multiplication between x and x is not allowed, and getting around it by doing something like x*(x+1) is not allowed either.
x into itself means x*x, not allowed.
I tried doing something like this

1. (x * (2)) - (-x)
2. (x * (-2)) - (-x)

and for x = 5 results were, 15 and -5

for x = -5 results were -15 and 5

I could not identify anything that could make a clear distinction between 5 and -5.

Is it even possible to do it?

Comment: This is not clear.  What operations exactly are allowed?  What does it mean to say we can multiply but we can't multiply $x$ by itself?  What exactly can we do with $x$?

Comment: What do you mean "to differentiate between negative and positive numbers"?

Comment: @lulu it mean to say we can multiply x to another known number but we can't multiply x to x i.e. x^2

Comment: @5xum to tell the difference between x and -x.

Comment: How is this different [from your last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4815950/29335)?

Comment: only if you could read man, but whatever delete it, i tried I can't @rschwieb

Comment: @Zetock I read them and came to the conclusion that the question you were asking in both amounted to the same thing.  So giving you the benefit of the doubt I decided to ask here.  I would certainly vote to reopen if you gave a convincing difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With just the operations you specify the answer is "no". To see why, think about the finite field $\mathbb{Z}_7$. In that field there is no arithmetic way to distinguish between $5$ and $-5 \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$.

If you are allowed to use the ordering of $\mathbb{Z}$ then just check which is greater than $0$.

Comment: thanks so much<3.

Comment: Maybe even more convincingly $\mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z$ where there truly *isn't* a way to distinguish between $5$ and $-5$ (because they *aren't* distinct.)

Answer (score 1):

Your question gets to the axiomatic nature of concepts of "positive" and "negative". In a general commutative ring $R$ with multiplicative identity $1$ one can formulate those axioms by saying that there is a subset $P \subset R$ satisfying various properties. First we have the trichotomy law, which says that for each $x \in R$ exactly one of the following happens: $x \in P$, or $-x \in P$, or $x=0$. Second, $P$ is closed under addition and multiplication. Third, $1 > 0$.

This works well in the ring $\mathbb Z$, in which case one can prove that $5$ is positive because $5$ is in the closure under addition of the multiplicative identity $1$:
$$1+1+1+1+1=5
$$
However, $-5$ is not in the closure of $1$ under addition. Another way to say it is that $-5$ is not positive because we have just proved that $5$ is positive, and the trichotomy law disallows that $5$ and $-5$ are both positive.

Comment: We are not told we have integers: this would not work in the same way for real numbers

Comment: We are not told much of *anything* in this question, are we? But it did feel like the integers were a reasonable assumption, given the tags on the question.